# How to generate and solve finite fields and insure integers instead of decimals for coefficients and random points

Tags: finite-fields, cryptography, lagrange-interpolation

**Background:**
I have tried to follow this tutorial on secret sharing: https://medium.com/@apogiatzis/shamirs-secret-sharing-a-numeric-example-walkthrough-a59b288c34c4. I have managed to use Shamir's secret sharing successfully and by hand I am able to work very simple problems out. I'm trying to convert this into code (using javascript and as few dependencies as possible). However I didn't understand why the author of the post used a finite field ? In Shamir's paper he used normal polynomial interpolation as an example.

**Issue**: I'm trying to use a large prime number value for L(0) and I had made the conscious decision of avoiding finite fields (as I don't really understand why they are being used, or how to use them properly). The issue is that when I select random points to generate the polynomial I end up with large decimal values and likewise when I generate the secret shards (each shard is one of the l(i)*y_i of the lagrange polynomial interpolation) to distribute they are actually large numbers with many decimal values. Unfortunately I'm failing to successfully decrypt the end result and I believe this is due to the accuracy of big numbers and the limitation of decimals in Javascript (or any language for that matter).

**Question**: How did the author of the above post generate such clean numbers (no decimals, just really large integer numbers)? Is this related to the use of a finite field ? How can I do this same thing efficiently ?

Detailed Step By Step:

1. Generate large prime
2. Pick k-1 random points
3. Use the large prime and the k-1 random points to generate the coefficients for the polynomial
4. Randomly select k number of x values between 1 to phi (where phi=(p-1)*(p-q), where p & q are 2 large primes such that p*q=n and n is a key size X bytes long)
5. Evaluate k number of x values on the polynomial for the y value
6. use the X,Y values to create the lagrange polynomial interpolation.

Thanks for this one !!!!!!!

Comment: I may be wrong, but I get the feeling that your problem is created by doing division with a data type designed for representing real numbers instead of integers modulo a prime (i.e. a simple finite field). Say, if your "large" prime were $29$, and Lagrange interpolation calls for division by $7$, you should observe that $7\cdot(-4)\equiv\pmod{29}$, and instead of dividing integer by seven you should multiply by $-4$, and then take the remainder modulo $29$. The modular inverse (modulo a truly large prime) can in general be found using extended Euclid.

Comment: Ok so I have managed to improve the state of my encryption/decryption. But unfortunately have gotten stuck still with weird decimal secret shards. I believe it isd due to the reason you have mentioned. But I don't quite understand your comment. Basically, I am doing ((x - x0) / (xj-x0) )* y ... mod (n).... so I don't really get how you are converting from dividing to multiplying using modular inverse ? that didn't make sense to me

Comment: When you divide by $x_j-x_0$ you are multiplying by $k=(x_j-x_0)^{-1}$, the modular inverse. That is, the integer $k$ should satisfy $k(x_j-x_0)\equiv1\pmod n$.

Comment: ok wow thanks so much sorry like I mentioned below so many gaps in my knowledge ! I've been able to understand this now and this should help me out a lot thanks !!!!!!

Comment: Great. When you do it right the coefficients of the interpolation polynomial should be integers modulo $n$ (or whatever modulus the description specifies).

Comment: If you think of those coefficients as real numbers, then the values of the polynomial become large. Remember to reduce the values modulo $n$ to make them fixed size (probably important for the implementation). Anyway, do exact integer arithmetic everywhere.

Comment: I managed to get the first part I needed done. A healthy combination of what you suggested and what Robert suggested in the comments... Not sure how to award this one

Answer (score 1):

Roundoff error is likely to be bad news if you're trying to do one of these computations with floating-point numbers.  It means that floating-point arithmetic doesn't obey
the standard laws of algebra: e.g. in general $(a+b)+c$ is not the same as $a + (b+c)$
when roundoff is involved.  For any of these computations to work reliably you'll want to use exact integer arithmetic, either with a "bignum" package or with a language that has support for that built-in.

Comment: Thanks Robert, but how do I insure that the numbers are in fact integers ? like I'm basically just picking random X values here, is there some better method to insure that the Y values I'm getting are integers (for example will finite fields do this, I don't get it at all)

Comment: If you do all calculations in the integers mod $p$, the results will be integers mod $p$.

Comment: ahhh ok so some p(x) mod n where x is a whole number? Can I still use the matrix method for solving for the coefficients the same way I would do with any p^n polynomial ?

Comment: Sorry I have weird gaps in my Mathematics knowledge so thats why some of this stuff doesn't come super easy to me

Comment: The same Lagrange interpolation formulas work perfectly well in the integers modulo a prime, in fact better (you don't have to worry about numerical difficulties such as the Runge phenomenon, because all computations are exact).  The coefficients and the $x$ values should all be integers mod $p$.  Note that there are only $p$ distinct integers mod $p$, so your polynomial should have degree less than $p-1$ (which makes sense since $x^p \equiv x \mod p$ for any integer $x$).

Comment: Ok right, I think you have actually helped me here resolve my issue. I'm going to get back to my task for the next day or so and I'll jump back in here and give this the approved answer based on the comments you have mentioned. Thanks ! Will let you know if I have additional issues.